# SMBUp: No SMB3?

Tags: macos, sharing, samba, smb

I'm trying to configure an OS X box with Samba using SMBUp. I installed SMBUp, installed SAMBA through it, and configured my users and shares. The only issue is when I check which protocol version I'm using, I'm using SMB1

Ok, fine. But when I try and change the protocol version in SMBUp, there is only LANMAN/CORE/NT protocols as options. I tried manually editing the configuration file in /opt/local/etc/samba3/smb.conf and changing the minimum protocol to SMB3, but that didn't work at all.

When I used OS X's built-in file sharing, I could connect via SMB3, but I only got around 10MB/s over ethernet... Not very good at all.

I'm very new to this whole thing and I couldn't find much documentation pertaining to my issue.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

EDIT:

I tried using (rebooting after running it):

```
sudo sh -c "echo '[default]' >> /etc/nsmb.conf; echo 'smb_neg=smb3_only' >> /etc/nsmb.conf"
```

But that just prevented my share from mounting.

Answer (score 0):

The version of Samba included in SMBUp is lower 3.6.something. SMB2 and SMB3 support was added in 4.0. Now I just have to figure out how to update Samba...

Cheers

EDIT:

Right, Samba devs stopped supporting OS X and I keep getting an error about not having GnuTls installed even though it is installed. So I can't compile it.

Great. I'm going to go die in a hole now.